# Extract Text Data from a Div Tag but not a from a Child H3 Tag

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have an HTML snippet that I need to get data from using BeautifuSoup:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <div class="sidebar-box">
            <h3><i class="fa fa-users"></i> Management Team</h3>
                        Chairman, Director
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar-box">
            <h3><i class="fa fa-male"></i> Teacher</h3>
                        John Doe
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar-box">
            <h3><i class="fa fa-mortar-board"></i> Awards </h3>
                        National Top Quality Educational Development
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar-box">
            <h3><i class="fa fa-building"></i> School Type</h3>
                        Secondary
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I need to get the `.text` value of the second `div` from the top "John Doe", but not the `.text` value inside the `h3` tag in that `div`.
My challenge is that currently I get both text values as in this code snippet:

```
# Python 3.7, BeautifulSoup 4.7
# html variable is equal to the above HTML snippet
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup4 = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
# Get School Head Teacher
school_head_teacher = soup4.find_all('div', {'class':'sidebar-box'})
school_head_teacher = school_head_teacher[1].text.strip()
print(school_head_teacher)
```

This outputs:

```
Teacher
                        John Doe
```

However, I only need the John Doe value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I offered 2 solutions. The first not the most elegant solution. But just off the top of my head quickly, you can split that again and join together everything after 'Teacher'

**Option 1:**

```
html = '''
!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <div class="sidebar-box">
            <h3><i class="fa fa-users"></i> Management Team</h3>
                        Chairman, Director
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar-box">
            <h3><i class="fa fa-male"></i> Teacher</h3>
                        John Doe
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar-box">
            <h3><i class="fa fa-mortar-board"></i> Awards </h3>
                        National Top Quality Educational Development
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar-box">
            <h3><i class="fa fa-building"></i> School Type</h3>
                        Secondary
        </div>
    </body>
</html>'''



from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup4 = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
# Get School Head Teacher
school_head_teacher = soup4.find_all('div', {'class':'sidebar-box'})
school_head_teacher = school_head_teacher[1].text.strip()

school_head_teacher = school_head_teacher.split()[1:]
school_head_teacher = ' '.join(school_head_teacher)

print(school_head_teacher)
```

**Output:**

```
print(school_head_teacher)
John Doe
```

**Option 2:**

This one I think is a bit better. You find the tag that has `Teacher`. Then you get the parent tag. Then since you want the second part, you use `.next_sibling` and the strip it.

```
soup4(text=re.compile('Teacher'))[0].parent.next_sibling.strip()
```

I had it in a for loop incase there's multiple teachers. But you can substitute the top code instead of the `for` loop

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

soup4 = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
# Get School Head Teacher
for elem in soup4(text=re.compile('Teacher')):
    print (elem.parent.next_sibling.strip())
```

Comment: I am accepting your solution, the 'Option 2' really. It fully meets my needs, much pythonic and then even meets some use cases I didn't include in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

teacher_name = soup.find_all('div', class_='sidebar-box')
print(teacher_name[1].contents[2].strip())
```

Output:

```
John Doe
```

Answer (score 1):

Since  `<div class="sidebar-box">
            <h3><i class="fa fa-male"></i> Teacher</h3>
                        John Doe
        </div>`

Since John Doe is the next-sibling of `<h3><i class="fa fa-male"></i> Teacher</h3>`

We can use a combination of find_next() and next_sibling on `<div class="sidebar-box">`

```
!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <div class="sidebar-box">
            <h3><i class="fa fa-users"></i> Management Team</h3>
                        Chairman, Director
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar-box">
            <h3><i class="fa fa-male"></i> Teacher</h3>
                        John Doe
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar-box">
            <h3><i class="fa fa-mortar-board"></i> Awards </h3>
                        National Top Quality Educational Development
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar-box">
            <h3><i class="fa fa-building"></i> School Type</h3>
                        Secondary
        </div>
    </body>
</html>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
# Get School Head Teacher
school_head_teacher = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'sidebar-box'})
head_teacher = school_head_teacher[1].find_next().next_sibling
print(head_teacher)
```

By this way you can loop over the other divs too that follow the same pattern.

```
for school_info in school_head_teacher:
    print (school_info.find_next().next_sibling)
```